# Error in MYSQL syntax with WHERE command

Tags: php, variables

Getting this error-

Not sure why, I have looked over it several of times.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE agentclient = 'admin'' at line 1

In this code-

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE agentclient SET email='$email2', phone='$phone2', Streetaddress='$address2', faxnumber='$faxnumber2', website='$website2', bio='$bio2', WHERE agentclient = '$agentclient2'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You have an extra comma in your statement, just before the WHERE.

Comment: Can you print your query in full?

Comment: Use mysqli/pdo and prepared statements, or at least put every SQL token on a new line, improving readability also makes it easier to detect those syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma before where is wrong, try:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE agentclient SET email='$email2', phone='$phone2', Streetaddress='$address2', faxnumber='$faxnumber2', website='$website2', bio='$bio2' WHERE agentclient = '$agentclient2'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE [...] bio='$bio2', WHERE agentclient = '$agentclient2'")[...]
                                            ^ this is wrong
```